# Rails Associations Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many-through, belongs-to

I have an issue seeding my data for some reason.
I feel like something is off with my model associations.

Anyone sees what's wrong?

I have 4 models - as you can see,
and I also attached the schema and the error.

Thanks for helping!

**MODELS**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_secure_password

    has_many :cuisines
    has_many :dishes, through: :cuisine
    has_many :comments
end
```

```
class Dish < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :cuisine
    has_many :comments
    belongs_to :user, through: :cuisine
end


class Cuisine < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :dishes
end



class Comment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :dish
end



**SCHEMA**

create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "content"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "dish_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "cuisines", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "country"
    t.string "picture"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
  end

  create_table "dishes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "picture"
    t.string "ingredients"
    t.string "directions"
    t.string "cook_time"
    t.string "yield"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "cuisine_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "username"
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

end



**SEED FILE**

User.create(name: "Adi", username: "adi3", password: "password")

italian = Cuisine.create(country: "Italy", picture: "https://www.delonghi.com/Global/recipes/multifry/pizza_fresca.jpg", user_id:1)
pizza = italian.dishes.create(name: "Pizza", picture: "https://d1uz88p17r663j.cloudfront.net/original/4274048cd5f17c49dfee280f77a3739d_Cheese-Pizza_HB-2.jpg", ingredients: "flour, water, yeast, oil, salt, cheese, olives", directions: "mix everything together and add toppings", cook_time: "30 min", yield: "1 big pizza", cuisine_id:1)
adi = User.first
adi_pasta = adi.dishes.create(name: "Pomodoro Pasta", picture: "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/_mkIjqOA29bzih8kz98RjBqf6KbLaan2ReyAzM2-Vj7SPDWGF24vPLz3zdTiwRdHaDdn6ed5kHdUUWkyoOQ83ZE=s640-c-rw-v1-e365", ingredients: "olive oil, garlic, basil, tomato, pasta", directions: "mix everything, cook pasta and top it up", cook_time: "20 min", yield: "4 portions", cuisine_id:1)
adi.comments.create(content: "Great easy tomato pasta", dish: adi_pasta, user_id:1, dish_id:2)


**ERROR**
```

// ☆♥☆ > rails db:seed
rails aborted!
ArgumentError: Unknown key: :through. Valid keys are: :class_name, :anonymous_class, :primary_key, :foreign_key, :dependent, :validate, :inverse_of, :strict_loading, :autosave, :required, :touch, :polymorphic, :counter_cache, :optional, :default
/Users/username/project-backend/app/models/dish.rb:4:in `class:Dish'

Answer (score 1):

The issue has nothing to do with your seed file. In your dish class you have defined a `belongs_to` with the through option:

```
class Dish < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cuisine
  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :user, through: :cuisine
end
```

This is not possible since `belongs_to` places the foreign key on this models table. What you intended to use is a `has_one` association:

```
class Dish < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cuisine
  has_many :comments
  has_one :user, through: :cuisine
end
```

But honestly it does not make very much sense to use indirect assocation here in the first place - why would the dishes created be associated automatically with the user that created the cuisine? Instead you just want a standard belongs_to association:

```
class Dish < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cuisine
  belongs_to :user 
  has_many :comments
end
```

I would call the association something more descriptive though like `creator`.

Comment: I tried that and still get :  

rails db:seed
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :cuisine in model User 

Do i need to run migration or anything before I run rails db:seed again, after changing the association?

Comment: Yes. You need to ensure that the dish table has a `user_id` column.

Comment: This was super helpful! I'm a total begginer.. thank you so much :)